# How can i get embed JSON Data from Website with Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a device to collect energy data with a webinterface on it and sadly no API.

There is a JSON stored in window.dataJSON.

I can get the value of it with: `console.log(JSON.stringify(window.dataJSON));` via the Chrome Debugger.

But my question is: How can i get this data with python? 
I know i can get the Sourcecode of the page with:

```
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen("10.10.10.10")
page_source = response.read()
```

But how can i read the JSON stored in window.dataJSON?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window` object exists only in a browser. So to get property of `window`, you should use a browser to do it.

You can use [Selenium](http://seleniumpython.readthedocs.io/installation.html) :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.example.com')

result = driver.execute_script('return JSON.stringify(window.dataJSON)')
```

And you can change `webdriver` to use `Headless Chrome` or `PhatomJS` if you don't want a browser to show up.

Maybe you need to tell `driver` to wait if `dataJSON` is assigned to `window` asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can i get dataJSON without window and without a browser? Your solution seems a little hackish.

Comment: you can take a look at the source code to see how `dataJSON` is loaded, maybe you can find an `url` with which you can get the data directly, or it's just in source code

Comment: Sadly no. But i think your solution is good enough. Its just for a project.